# Why the function is not returning all the children recursively?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Start()
{
    var allchildren = AddDescendantsWithTag(transform);
}
```

and

```
private List<GameObject> AddDescendantsWithTag(Transform parent)
{
        List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            list.Add(child.gameObject);
            AddDescendantsWithTag(child);
        }

        return list;
}
```

But it return only the children of the first level under the parent.

And I want to loop deep to the end.

The script is attached to transform and transform is also the parent.

Comment: One child - multiple **children** (not "childs")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating a new list repeatedly then throwing it away.  You probably just want to allocate a single list and add to it.  Try this:

```
void Start()
{
    var allchilds = new List<GameObject>();
    AddDescendantsWithTag(transform, allchilds);
}

private void AddDescendantsWithTag(Transform parent,  List<GameObject> list)
{
    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        list.Add(child.gameObject);
        AddDescendantsWithTag(child, list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you make your recursive call, you're throwing away the value, so that information is not passing back up the recursion. It's an easy fix.

```
private List<GameObject> AddDescendantsWithTag(Transform parent)
{
    List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();

    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        list.Add(child.gameObject);
        list.AddRange(AddDescendantsWithTag(child));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  I only added another answer for the sake of performance (to avoid copying and allocating new lists each time the method is re-entered)

Comment: @Tim Yes, on reflection, hugely inefficient. Hopefully it gives OP some insight into recursion tho.